# Conditional formatting based on frequency in column and value of adjacent cell (for each previous entry)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to format a column (T) where names are entered using a data validation drop-down list.
Each name is assigned to a project so in the previous column (S) I have used conditional formatting to give a status indicator of the final phase of the project (entering the number 2 gives a green traffic light indicating a complete phase).

Ideally what I wanted to do was disable the possibility of selecting any name that has a workload of four or more projects (workload is being captured in a separate sheet where the list of names is being taken from).
But after a lot of trial and error (more error than anything tbh!) I don't think this is possible.
As a work-around then, what I was hoping to do was format column T so when someones name is listed in the column for a fourth time and the status of the final phase of each of these four projects is not complete (i.e. less than 2) the cell goes amber, or an icon within conditional formatting appears.
Adding a name five or more times without changing the status of previously assigned projects would produce a red cell, or an icon.

In [this sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKIwm.jpg), I have two choices of Project Managers, Joe and Bob, both of whom have previously been assigned four projects. Joe hasn't completed the final "achieving results" phase of the last four projects he has been assigned so he still has an active workload of four projects, indicated by yellow dots which are created by entering a 1 in column S. Bob has no active workload with all four of his previously assigned projects marked as complete, indicated by a green dot which are created by entering a 2 in column S. In this sample, I want to set it up that any attempt to add Joe to T9 as the project manager for a new project would produce an error message preventing me from assigning him to any more projects, or T9 would be conditionally formatted to show that Joe has exceeded workload capacity. This would adjust based on Joe completing older projects and his capacity increasing. As Bob has no active projects, I would be able to add him with no problem.

*Edit in response to a number of comments (which I am very grateful for!)*

- Currently there is no interaction between column S and column T at all.
- I'm struggling to provide an example of what I would like the results to look like. As I say above, ideally I would like a set up that prevents a project manager being selected in column T if their name is already present in column T  on four previous occasions and the cell adjacent to each instance of that name in column S contains a 1 (yellow dot).

I know this is super complicated, or at least it seems like it is to me but it would make my life so much easier if it can be done. Am I expecting too much from excel or is there someone out there that might be able to give me a hand. Even an alternative workaround would be much appreciated.

Hoping this isn't duplicating a question or thread elsewhere on the site, but I have been looking for a while now and can't seem to find anything that works for me. That said, a reason for that might be due to the complexity of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: please insert some sample data with desired output too, without that it's very difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: It’s still hard to understand the full scope of what you want. Please expand your example data to show the ***values*** in Column `S`. Are they just 1 and 2? Please expand your example data to show the interaction of Columns `S` and `T`; e.g., show two different names that appear four times in Column `T` but that get different results based on the corresponding values in Column `S`. And, as Máté Juhász already asked, show the results you want, too — the input data is only part of what we need. It might also be nice to state explicitly how you’re formatting Column ``S``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to go the conditional formatting route as a potential solution. The solution is fairly simple:

1. Create a separate table, perhaps on a separate worksheet, to count the number of active projects each person is working on. Use `CountIFS()` to provide a count based on multiple criteria, which in your case, is if the cell value is "Bob White", and the project status is not completed, then tally it up. Do this for each person, so each person has an active project count.

   ```
   =COUNTIFS(DataSet!$T:$T,A2,DataSet!$S:$S,"<>1")
   ```

   [[image of the above]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6phP3.png)
2. Create a conditional formatting rule for your person column in your main table, that uses a `VLookup` function to return the number of active projects, and format the cell if the number of active projects is greater than 4.

   ```
   =IF(VLOOKUP($T1,Counts!$A:$B,2,FALSE)>3,1,0)
   ```

   [[image of the above]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iVk1.png)

   Apply the rule to Column `T`. [[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4bpg.png)

The result should look like this:

[image: Conditional Formatting Result]

Notes: To make the max number of projects dynamic, instead of typing in the max number of projects into the formulas, use a worksheet cell to designate the max number, and have your formulas reference that cell. In the counts table, you can simply type in new names, and copy down the counting formula. Let me know if you have any questions, or need any more help on this!

Comment: This looks like a reasonable approach.   But please type as much information into your post ***as text*** as possible — specifically, the formulas you used.

Comment: Added the formulas. How's that? I'm new here, and a bit bored at work, so I thought I could keep myself busy by posting some solutions to Excel problems on Superuser! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Yes, that’s much better.

Comment: Zaxximus_Prime, thanks for your suggestion and this is very close to what I expected the solution might be. I have to say, while I like to think of myself as reasonably well versed on excel, VLOOKUP is one function I have always struggled with. At present I have, on a separate sheet, a count of the number of active projects each manager has, how could I incorporate this into your solution? Also, is there a way of only highlighting the fourth occurrence of a managers name, as opposed to all instances of it? Thanks for you help

Comment: Got there in the end on this one...thanks everyone for your contributions and especially @Zaxximus_Prime who put me on the right path and then some.